# RabbitMQ Java client - How to sensibly handle exceptions and shutdowns?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

Here's what I know so far (please correct me):

In the RabbitMQ Java client, operations on a channel throw `IOException` when there is a general network failure (malformed data from broker, authentication failures, missed heartbeats).

Operations on a channel can also throw the `ShutdownSignalException` unchecked exception, typically an `AlreadyClosedException` when we tried to perform an action on the channel/connection after it has been shut down.

The shutting down process happens in the event of ["network failure, internal failure or explicit local shutdown"](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#shutdown) (e.g. via channel.close() or connection.close()). The shutdown event propagates down the "topology", from Connection -> Channel -> Consumer, and when the Channel it calls the Consumer's `handleShutdown()` method gets called.

A user can also add a shutdown listener which is called after the shutdown process completes.

**Here is what I'm missing:**

1. Since an IOException indicates a network failure, does it also initiate a shutdown request?
2. How does using auto-recovery mode affect shutdown requests? Does it cause channel operations to block while it tries to reconnect to the channel, or will the ShutdownSignalException still be thrown?

**Here is how I'm handling exceptions at the moment, is this a sensible approach?**

My setup is that I'm polling a QueueingConsumer and dispatching tasks to a worker pool. The rabbitmq client is encapsulated in `MyRabbitMQWrapper` here. When an exception occurs polling the queue I just gracefully shutdown everything and restart the client. When an exception occurs in the worker I also just log it and finish the worker.

My biggest worry (related to Question 1): Suppose an IOException occurs in the worker, then the task doesn't get acked. If the shutdown does not then occur, I now have an un-acked task that will be in limbo forever.

Pseudo-code:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            run();
            //Easy way to restart the client, the connection has been
            //closed so RabbitMQ will re-queue any un-acked tasks.
            log.info("Shutdown occurred, restarting in 5 seconds");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
      MyRabbitMQWrapper rw = new MyRabbitMQWrapper("localhost");

      try {
        rw.connect();

        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
           try {
               //Wait for a message on the QueueingConsumer
               MyMessage t = rw.getNextMessage();
               workerPool.submit(new MyTaskRunnable(rw, t));
           } catch (InterruptedException | IOException | ShutdownSignalException e) {
               //Handle all AMQP library exceptions by cleaning up and returning
               log.warn("Shutting down", e);
               workerPool.shutdown();
               break;
           }
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Could not connect to broker", e);
      } finally {
        try { 
            rw.close(); 
        } catch(IOException e) { 
            log.info("Could not close connection");
        }
      }
    }
}

class MyTaskRunnable implements Runnable {
    ....

    public void run() {
        doStuff();
        try {
            rw.ack(...);
        } catch (IOException | ShutdownSignalException e) {
            log.warn("Could not ack task");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to get an IOException thrown by calling `channel.basicCancel(null)`. Subsequent operations on the channel did not throw a ShutdownSignalException, so the answer is that the IOException does not guarantee a shutdown request.

Comment: Therefore IOException could lead to unacked task... I now shut down the connection and restart when an IOException occurs.

Comment: If a connection/channel is closed, unacked messages are pushed back to the origin queue.